# Is a set of the number of circles passing through the origin a finite set or infinite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of the circles passing through the origin is an infinite set as there are infinitely many circles that pass through the origin.
From what I understand, the only element in the set of the **number** of circles passing through the origin should be infinity, making the set a finite set. My teacher says that it is not a finite set, but an infinite set as infinity is not an element, it is only a way of representing an extremely large number. Which one is it then?

Edit: If I'm understanding it correctly, the set of the number of circles passing through the origin can also be rewritten as the set of the cardinality of the set of all circles passing through the origin. The cardinality of the set of all circles passing through the origin is $\infty$, therefore making the set of the cardinality a finite set. Is this a valid interpretation?

Comment: A set only containing a number, infinite or not, has only one element, and is therefore a finite set.

Comment: It is a finite subset of $[-\infty,\infty]$, not $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Let S be the set of circles passing through the origin in the Cartesian plane.

Let $C$ is a circle with center
That is, $S = {C : C  (a,b)  r,  s.t. a^2 + b^2 = r^2}$. Is S a finite or infinite set?

We can see that S is an infinite set because for any positive real number r, we can construct a circle with radius r that passes through the origin. Specifically, we can define a circle C with center (0,0) and radius r by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. Therefore, there are infinitely many circles that pass through the origin, and S is an infinite set.

Note that while we cannot include infinity as an element of S, we can describe the size or cardinality of S using infinity. In this case, we would say that the cardinality of S is $\infty$, which means that S is an infinite set.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, but that is not what I had asked. I am aware that the set of all circles passing through the origin is an infinite set. What I'm asking instead is whether the set of the **number** of circles passing through the origin is a finite set or not.

Comment: It is indeed finite. Its only element is the cardinal number corresponding to the uncountably infinite, but that's still only a single symbol/element. I suspect that your teacher is hung up on the set of all circles passing through the origin instead (which is uncountably infinite). At what level of maths are you studying if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Sorry did you ask me? or Entity 903?

Comment: Entity 903. I tried @'ing them but it didn't seem to want to work lol

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I just got into 11th Grade. So basics of Sets in 11th Grade Maths (If you want more information about what is there specifically in what I learn, check this link. https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?kemh1=1-14)